# Can we configure different shells for different users on a single Linux/Unix distribution?

Tags: shell, login, accounts

Well, this is not something that I want to do but I ask this question to know more about Shell configuration in Unix/Linux systems. So, the situation that I want an answer to is the following -:

As we have different shells made available to us by a Unix/Linux system is it possible for us to configure a different shell for every user authorized to access the system. So, let's say that Tom, Dick and Harry are 3 users authorized to use the system "Unix" and I want "Tom" to use the shell **zsh** , Dick to use **tcsh** and Harry to use the **bash** shell. How can I do this and is this even possible?

Comment: Type `man chsh` and you should have your answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, valid shells are listed in `/etc/shells`. Any user can change their default shell by using `chsh` as long as it's in the `/etc/shells` file.

Second, if you want to add a shell to `/etc/shells` you can, if you remove an entry from there, especially /bin/sh you are probably going to screw up the system, because `/bin/login` will NOT normally launch off a shell that's not listed there.

More info is available in **chsh**(1), **login.defs**(5), and **passwd**(5) man pages.

This ability has been around for a long time (I believe BSD 4.x)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, different users can have different shells setup. You can change them with, for example, the `chsh` command. To change the current user's shell to bash (assuming it's in /bin/bash):

```
chsh -s /bin/bash [username]
```

You can also modify your `/etc/passwd` file manually and change the part which specifies the shell for that user. For example:

```
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
```

The last part in each line of your /etc/passwd, which will look something like the line above, after the last `:`, specifies the shell for that user.

Comment: You really shouldn't modify /etc/passwd by hand though

Comment: But lets say that I am a system administrator and I want to restrict the user to use a specific shell, can I do that and how?

Comment: Sure, if you don't know what you're doing!

Comment: can you like point me to an example or illustrate the example I took, how do I do that?

Comment: @AnkitSablok Your question doesn't mention *restricting* user's shells, only *configuring them*. Restricting a user from running a command (i.e. not letting them type `bash` at a `tcsh` prompt) is a very different question.

Comment: @IMSoP : got it, will not ask here but I was curious to know if even that's possible? :)

Comment: @AnkitSablok, yes, it is. Look into this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chsh`!

```
chsh -s /bin/sh user_name
```